# Чтение матрицы из .txt файла

Tags: python

> Введите из текстового файла целочисленную матрицу размером 6х8.
> Переверните матрицу, поменяв 1-ю строку с 6-й, 2-ю с 5-й, 3-ю с 4-й, и
> запишите полученную матрицу в другой файл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
with open('m.txt') as file:
    file = file.read()
    q = file.replace(' ', '')  # убираю лишние пробелы

    f1 = q[0:8]                # в переменную f1 сохраняю первую строку
    f2 = q[9:16]               # в f2 - вторую строку
    f3 = q[17:24]
    f4 = q[25:32]
    f5 = q[33:40]
    f6 = q[41:48]
```

В правильном ли я направлении иду и как быть дальше?

Comment: `f = open('m.txt, 'r')`     
`matrix = [line.replace("\n", "").split() for line in f]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В файле:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
8 7 9 6 5 4 1 2
1 2 0 1 4 8 7 5
4 5 2 3 6 9 8 7
0 1 2 3 0 1 2 5
2 1 4 5 6 9 8 7
1 2 5 4 7 8 5 2
10 1 2 4 5 6 9 8
```

---

```
In [5]: with open('matrix.txt') as f:
   ...:     matrix = [list(map(int, row.split())) for row in f.readlines()]
   ...:

In [6]: matrix
Out[6]:
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [8, 7, 9, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 8, 7, 5],
 [4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 5],
 [2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7],
 [1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2],
 [10, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8]]

In [7]: matrix.reverse()

In [8]: matrix
Out[8]:
[[10, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8],
 [1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2],
 [2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 5],
 [4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7],
 [1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 8, 7, 5],
 [8, 7, 9, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Ну и запись в другой файл соответственно:

```
In [14]: with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    ...:     for row in matrix:
    ...:         f.write(' '.join(map(str, row)) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 6
matr = [[] for i in range(n)] # "объявляет" матрицу(двумерный массив)
with open('m.txt') as file:
    for i in range(n):
        matr[i] = [int(t) for t in file.readline().split()] #читает всю строку, делит по пробелам, и сохраняет как массив интов записывая в строку матрицы
matr.reverse()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open('m.txt') 
matrix = [line.replace("\n", "").split() for line in f]
matrix.reverse()
```

Или если вам конкретно нужно поменять местами указанные в условии строки:

```
matrix[0], matrix[5] = matrix[5], matrix[0]
matrix[1], matrix[4] = matrix[4], matrix[1]
matrix[2], matrix[3] = matrix[3], matrix[2]
```

Comment: благодарю, Семпай